# How to get the contacts from a group of Whatsapp in android?

Tags: android, contacts, whatsapp

I would like to know if it is possible to take information somehow. I want to know if I can get the contacts from one group (I would just want the name and the number).

Comment: hi @mxmolins i see no answers here . How did you solved your problem?

Comment: Any answers to this?

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp did not publish any official APIs.
WhatApp doesn't have any public API for Android There were some 3rd party APIs that did integrate Whatsapp but all were found illegal.

I do not believe there is any way to now get hold of the WhatsApp phone number from outside the WhatsApp app.

https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/